# BigQuery producing "left join" results rather than a Full outer join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the below query:

```
SELECT
  OUTPUTS.calculation_id,
  SCENARIOS.scenario_id,
  OUTPUTS.account_id,
  ACCOUNTS.account_name,
  OUTPUTS.output_date,
  OUTPUTS.output_value

FROM
 `p.Trunk.OUTPUTS` as OUTPUTS

  full outer join `p.Trunk.ACCOUNTS` as ACCOUNTS
  on OUTPUTS.account_id = ACCOUNTS.account_id

  join `p.Trunk.SCENARIOS` as SCENARIOS
  on OUTPUTS.calculation_id = SCENARIOS.calculation_id
```

I want to use the resulting values to create a pivot table that has output_date grouped by year in the columns, account_name in the rows and the output_value as values.

All account_id in OUTPUTS have a corresponding account_id in ACCOUNTS from which I get the account_name

However, there are many account_id in ACCOUNTS without an entry in OUTPUTS but I still need to see these accounts as rows in the pivot table, with zero value for output_value.

When I try the query, it only provides me the account_name for which there is a corresponding entry in OUTPUTS (i.e. LEFT JOIN)

I was wondering what do I need to do to get a FULL RIGHT JOIN that shows me all the accounts, with those that have no entries in OUTPUTS showing a zero value for all the years?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried doing a left join rather than an inner join after the full outer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a LEFT JOIN and COALESCE

```
SELECT OUTPUTS.calculation_id
     , SCENARIOS.scenario_id
     , OUTPUTS.account_id
     , ACCOUNTS.account_name
     , OUTPUTS.output_date

     -- First non-null argument from the left
     , COALESCE(OUTPUTS.output_value, 0) AS output_value

FROM p.Trunk.OUTPUTS as OUTPUTS
FULL JOIN p.Trunk.ACCOUNTS as ACCOUNTS
   ON OUTPUTS.account_id = ACCOUNTS.account_id

LEFT JOIN p.Trunk.SCENARIOS as SCENARIOS
   ON OUTPUTS.calculation_id = SCENARIOS.calculation_id
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It does the trick of adding all the accounts and for those not in OUTPUTS, adding a zero value. However, I did not realise that to see those accounts with zero value in the pivot table I need to have a value in output_date and a record for each date. 

Do you know if there is any way to add those entries?

Comment: you can use for example COALESCE(OUTPUTS.output_date, '1901-01-01')

Comment: If you want one row for each date within a period, use a calendar table with those dates

Comment: Many thanks @Lennart, it works now with dates. :-)